# Are iOS Games all One Screen?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm hoping this isn't a terribly stupid question. I've developed iOS apps before, however I have only used Xamarin so I have not actually worked with Xcode and Apple's native language. Swift, however, caught my eye and so I am trying to get into doing it this way now.

My question..

I'm looking to develop a game, complete with menus and a signup/login system. How exactly does this work when it comes to the Views? I am using SpriteKit and have my Game View Controller. Is everything done in this one View, and just a matter of hiding/showing things on taps? Or should I be creating multiple views, and if so, what is the best practice for this?

Sorry if this comes off as an odd question. It sounds odd even to myself, but it does have me stumped. Just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: The SpriteKit very short tutorial gives you a rough idea of how a basic game would work: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW1  you use SKScenes, to show "screens" in your game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, many applications have multiple views and it sounds like you should consider more than one for you game. Implementing a multiple view application is a multistep process and I suggest you follow this Apple iOS Developer tutorial.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html